# indexeddb put not update a value, it creates a new (id)

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb

I have a table with form, surname, lastname, email and a rectangle.  I have to insert, in the rectangle, an array with arrays with points of timelines etc. I create a customer with form, surname, lastname and email, add them to indexeddb, load them later to insert the rectangle-array. After that, I want to put the `newobjectstore` in the indexeddb where the email is the same from my customer I choose/inserted. But with this code my array will be put in a new Objectstore with its own ID.

```
function cmd_SaveRec(hypeDocument, elementID)
{
    hypeDocument.getElementById('rectext').innerHTML = hypeDocument.getElementById('beschriftung').value;
    
    var store_cust = db.transaction(["customer"], "readwrite").objectStore("customer").index("rectangle");

    var cursorReq = store_cust.openCursor();
    cursorReq.onsuccess = function (e) {
        cursor = e.target.result;
        if(cursor) {
            if(cursor.value.email == mailAdd) 
            {
                //cursor.update([rec_ar]);
                if(store_cust.objectStore.put({rectangle: [rec_ar]}))
                {
                    console.info(store_cust.objectStore);
                    console.info('Gespeichert');
                    alert("Gespeichert");
                } else {
                    console.info('cmd_SaveRec::Problem');
                }   
            }
            cursor.continue();
        }       
    };

    cursorReq.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.dir(e);
    }    
}

var store_cust = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
        DB_STORE_NAME_CUSTOMER, { keyPath: 'cust_id', autoIncrement: true });

  store_cust.createIndex('form', 'form', { unique: false }); // 
  store_cust.createIndex('surname', 'surname', { unique: false });
  store_cust.createIndex('lastname', 'lastname', { unique: false });
  store_cust.createIndex('email', 'email', { unique: true });
  store_cust.createIndex('rectangle', 'rectangle', { unique: false, multiEntry: true });
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the object stores/indexes? I'm guessing that you're using a key generator (`{autoIncrement: true}`) and if so the answer is to call `put()` with the key: `store_cust.objectStore.put({rectangle: [rec_ar]}), cursor.primaryKey)` - but `update()` can be used to do the same thing.

Comment: copied the createObjectStore under the SaveRec function. But no, your code store_cust.objectStore.put({rectangle: [rec_ar]}), cursor.primaryKey) does the same, like my code. it saves the array in a new object.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

- Provide an identifier/key as a second parameter in `objectStor.put(data, key)` **or**
- Use a IDBCursor und update it [as stated here in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/update)

#### Explanation

As described in the docs:

> The put() method of the IDBObjectStore interface updates a given record in a database, or inserts a new record if the given item does not already exist. ([source developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/put))

Your used method `objectStore.put()` is for *insert or update*  tasks. If I get you right you're looking for an *update* - `cursor.update()` is your friend here (you commented out). - This is the preferred method here !

But you could do it with both methods. Say you would like to update but if the record not exists create one. In such a case the engine have to know if your record exists and what record do you try to update.

If your `objectStore` uses an **autoIncrementing primary key** the identifier of the record **is not in the record** itself so you have to provide the id as a second parameter to your `put()` function.

I find it easier to take care of the ids by myself. Then the id is part of the record (findable under the `keypath` you provided at objectStore-creation). **Then** your code could work as expected... certainly you have to add a key:value pair for an id.

#### Examples

```
// create a store with ids YOU handle e.g.
var request = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion+1);
request.onerror = errorHandler;
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
    var nextDB = request.result;
    if (!nextDB.objectStoreNames.contains('account')) {
        nextDB.createObjectStore('account', {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
    }
}

// Your record has to llok like this
{id: 123456789, rectangle: [rec_ar]}

// Now your code above should work
```

If you have a primary key in your db:

```
store_cust.objectStore.put({rectangle: [rec_ar]}, PRIMARY_KEY)
// where PRIMARY_KEY is the id of this specific record
```

#### By the way

**Don't use if-else to check the completness of the transaction** - it is asynchronus - if/else lies everytime here - use callbacks as I stated in my example above (`onsuccess`).

You should read the docs from my cite. Mozilla is a great ressource for indexedDB stuff.